# The fastest way to import datasets with comomn characters in their names?

Tags: r, import, dataset

I have the following sets of data into the directory:

[image]

As you could see they are named with common chacrters they share each other. Could anyone suggest any possible way to import them all together in one round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.files` with `pattern` would give the name of the files in the directory, you may use `lapply`/`map` to import them together.

```
#select files that start with RP and end with extension xls.
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '^RP.*\\.xls$')
data <- purrr::map(filenames, readxl::read_excel)
```

If all the files have same column names and you would like to import them as one combined dataframe then use `purrr::map_df` instead of `purrr::map`.

Comment: Thanks.  The second solution you've proposed ihaas worked exaclty in the way I would like to have them merged

Comment: since the merged dataset has repeated observation and I would like to have them ordered together those taken from the same patients (name column: ID), is there any possible implementation to enter in your code or is better to proceed on this purpose outside your command?

Comment: You may do `data <- data %>% arrange(ID)`.

Comment: Yep! That is exactly the solution I've applied. Thanks

Comment: I have a question again. I have to merge other three dataset with same row number (no NA) just with some numeric variables less, but the factor ones all shared between different datasets. Does anyone knows what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.files` in collect your files and `assign` to create variable table names:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.xls")
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  assign(gsub("\\.xls", "", files[i]), readxl::read_xls(files[i]))
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry if I ask this guys, but I'm quite in trouble with anothe question: I've posted it here today and I haven't the foggiest as to create tables (and in that particular way I've described)  for a word document. If you could please have a look I would be glad ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69675243/how-to-report-repeated-measures-anova-output-in-tables-on-a-word-text-file